# how to avoid white screen while page is loading via ajax or normal request

Tags: php, loading

I have encountered this problem before and so far I have applied ajax beforeSend:function() parameter to display a loading image, though for normal form requests and page reload is there any alternative way to display a loader instead of just a plain white background as to prevent clients from thinking the pages has crashed.

Comment: Success parameter to display a loader? The success handler is called when the after the call returned the response...

Comment: You are sending a response to the browser before you are completing your all your tasks server side.  The best practice is to complete all of your heavy lifting before you send a response.

Comment: @TheWolf sorry about that, I meant beforesend.

Comment: @Peter how would you do that? if it you are loading a query with thousands of values?

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey how would you trigger that event to only send a response after you are done with the server side scripts?

Comment: @magicianIam I'm not sure how you have your site structured but say you are echoing out your page header, then processing your form, then echoing out a response, etc etc you want to process your form before you echo or send anything to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to have a "loading" image as a background in the center of the body tag. The main wrapper of the app/site would be toggled for ajax calls and you only need to toggle a class on the main wrapper. While the wrapper is hidden you'll can see the loading imagen on the body until new content arrives. Pretty cheap way and looks nicely on mobile.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JlGIp)

Comment: so it will like onLoad="hide the loader to display the new contents"?

Comment: Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JlGIp), i'm kinda stupid to explain things sometimes :(